# Tradingview - PineScript - Convert Strategy from EMA v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

How to convert this EMA script from V2 to V5?

```
   //@version=2
  //Original author: Rajandran R from www.marketcalls.in

   study("Supertrend Alerts 1.1", overlay = true)

    cand_col = input(title="Color Candles", type=bool, defval=true)
    show_line = input(title="Show Supertrend Line", type=bool, defval=true)
    Factor = input(3, type=float)
    PD = input(7, minval = 1, maxval = 100)


    Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(PD))
    Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(PD))

    TrendUp = close[1] > TrendUp[1] ? max(Up, TrendUp[1]) : Up
    TrendDown = close[1] < TrendDown[1] ? min(Dn, TrendDown[1]) : Dn
    
    Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1], 1)
    TSL = Trend == 1 ? TrendUp : TrendDown
        
    linecolor = Trend == 1 ? color(green, 0) : color(red, 0)
    barcolor((cand_col and Trend == 1) ? color(green, 0) : na)
    barcolor((cand_col and Trend == -1) ? color(red, 0) : na)
    
    plot(show_line ? TSL : na, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2, title = "SuperTrend Line", transp=65)
    
    newup = cross(close,TSL) and close>TSL
    newdn = cross(TSL,close) and close<TSL
    
    plotshape(newup, "Long", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color(green, 0), size=size.normal)
    plotshape(newdn, "Short", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, color(red, 0), size=size.normal)
    
    alertcondition(newup, title='Supertrend Long', message='Supertrend: Long ')
    alertcondition(newdn, title='Supertrend Short', message='Supertrend: Short ')
    alertcondition(newup or newdn, title='Supertrend Signal', message='Supertrend: Long or Short ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easilly by following these steps:

1. First convert your script manually to V3 by using this manual:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed

2. After use auto-converter to v4.
3. And after that use auto-converter to v5.